# Why can't emoji be used as variable name in Python

Tags: python, emoji

Could someone explain why mathematical variables are allowed, but emoji variables are not?

```
>>> π = 3.14
>>> π
3.14
```

```
>>>  = 2
  File "<stdin>", line 1
     = 2
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers

Comment: To expand on @jonrsharpe's comment, because `unicodedata.category('')` is `'So'`, which isn't valid.

Comment: `π` is not a "mathematical variables" but a _letter_, although in a different alphabet. `` is not.

Comment: Note _normalisation_ can also create problems with dynamic access when using a broader character set for variable names, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/48063082/3001761. Sticking to ASCII is probably easier.

Comment: [Unicode identifiers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21867836/3890632)